# Does legalizing prostitution lead to an increase in human trafficking?

Tags: law, prostitution

This is a common argument against the legalization of prostitution, and I'm curious if there's any truth to the claim that human trafficking actually increase when prostitution is made legal.

Comment: I've also heard claims that legalizing prostitution lead to an increase, rather than a decrease, in the absolute amount of illegal prostitution.

Comment: +1 for Andrew. If you define human trafficking to also include consensual trafficked where women do want to be prostitute for bigger income, then obviously yes. I think legalization of prostitution should decrease forced prostitution and women trafficking. It's just economic common sense

Comment: It does increase consensual trafficking. Just like legalization of programming will increase the number immigrants coming to US to make programs. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @JimThio Trafficking is, by definition, illegal, so no, immigrants coming to a country to work as a prostitute wouldn't count.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. The claim makes absolutely no sense. Source: Economics 101. If you decrease the cost of being a prostitute (e.g. no more danger of arrest), you increase the supply of prostitutes. The reason for trafficking is that - given the payoff - not enough people want the job voluntarily, so you need to being in involuntary (slave) labor. Increasing the supply due to legalization removes that need. Please note that legalizing prostitution STILL keeps both trafficking and child exploitation laws in place.
2. Moreover, looks like there's absolutely no proof (despite major allegations by interested parties) that the center of legalized prostitution in the USA (e.g. Nevada) has a big trafficking problem.

   From http://www.lasvegassun.com/news/2007/jan/29/do-we-have-a-human-trafficking-problem/ :

   > Terri Miller, ATLAS's civilian director and long one of the top Nevada activists against the sexual exploitation of women and children, and her boss, Metro Capt. Terry Lesney, say the need for the group is clear: There is a "huge" and growing sex-oriented trafficking problem in Las Vegas.
   >
   > **Yet they quickly add that no statistics have ever been gathered and law enforcers never before have made it a top priority - so the scope of the problem still needs to be determined.**
   >
   > ... The task force's first task was to determine whether, in fact, there was a human-trafficking problem, Lesney says. **But because of the lack of hard data, she says, "we were struggling to quantify what we're dealing with."**
   >
   > ... The largest human trafficking bust in the area in recent years was Operation Jade Blade. A national sting in 2000 netted five Las Vegas Valley residents, who were arrested for trafficking Asian prostitutes into the city. The women had been smuggled into the country for a fee, then were forced to pay back their debt by working as prostitutes.

   Editorial note here - this is the LARGEST bust - and it's not, strictly speaking, about trafficking. The women came to the USA voluntarily. The crime was in forcing them to pay, and it **has nothing to do with prostitution** - the **same exact** problem exists/existed with Asians being smuggled all over the country and forced to work off their fees in sweatshops, often textile related.

   So, not only are the provable trafficking numbers WAY low (the article further details several - as in, less than 10 in several years) - there's absolutely ZERO proof on anyone's part that it's something specific to Las Vegas or has any correlation - never mind causation - with legalized prostitution. Remember, these are the people who are in CHARGE of fixing the supposed problem.

Comment: The crime you are describing **is** called trafficking. And in this case it is connected to prostitution (though whether the connection is causal remains to be seen).

Comment: @Konrad - that's just semantics games, sorry. Whatever the legal definition, an implication made by people who don't like prostitution is that the prostitutes are **forcibly** dragged into the trade and would not have been if it was illegal. Both of which as pure BS - as noted, even the biggest bust involved people **voluntarily** coming to US, and a vast majority of such cases nationwide are not involved in sex trade, legal or illegal.

Comment: @DVK It’s not semantics. The question is whether there is any force involved, and to what extent people involved have free will. If they are forced to work as prostitutes then this *is* trafficking by any common definition of the term (and agreed, there are many). I agree with your overall conclusion but there are more ways of trafficking than just plain kidnapping people.

Comment: Just a note: Prostitution is NOT legal in Las Vegas.

Comment: @Rusty - correct. Fixed.

Comment: "Don't trust economics 101." -Behavioral economics

Comment: @Borror0 - lol... However, see part #2. People who are in charge of combatting the "problem" aren't able to produce any statistics, and what they can, doesn't support the hysterical "lead to an **increase** in human trafficking" claim being asked about

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment, saying that the claim makes no sense based on our current understanding of human behavior is arrogant and misguided. Our assumptions or understanding can be wrong. Empirical evidence is required, especially in a file as complicated as this one. While my gut tells me that the claim is false, it would be arrogance to rely solely on my gut. This question cannot be answered by anything but a thorough look at the file, which this answer does not provide. As a result, I'm downvoting this answer.

Comment: @DVK: Netherlands - where prostitution is legal - is a top destination for victims of human trafficking according to the UN. There may be problems with those statics, too, (and feel free to demolish them, if there are) but you cannot dismiss the claim as easily as you have.

Comment: I'm under the impression that most victims get into this by promises of good wages, not by kidnapping (though that also happens). In those cases, you could say it's voluntary, but they are being lied to (they are often not more than children), and it's no less tragic.

Comment: I think your source has introduced a deliberate bias or deliberate missinformation. Prostetution is illeagal in Las Vegas. Only certain counties in Nervada permit prostetution. Thus the claims made in the article are bogus. Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Nevada#Legal_situation

Comment: "There's absolutely ZERO proof" sounds like an unprovable claim to me, regardless of the subject matter.

Comment: It is a semantic game. Trafficking is defined to include CONSENSUAL immigration for sex purpose. So UN may be right. Yes prostitution increase trafficking. They're just hiding the fact that most increased trafficking are for consensual trafficking.

Comment: I don't see how the first part of your answer is anything but speculation. The second part seems like an interesting anecdote but I don't see any reason to apply the principal to the entire profession.

Comment: @MrHen - If you consider basic laws of supply and demand "speculation", I can't help it.

Comment: @DVK: I consider the application of such laws to the subject of human trafficking speculation. Unless you have some sort of reference suggesting that human trafficking levels follow traditional supply and demand?

Comment: @MrHen - is there some reason why human trafficing is somehow uber special and doesn't follow the laws that EVERY OTHER economic activity does? That's like saying "give me a reference that grapes follow laws of gravity" or "give me a reference that selection and evolutionary pressure applies to hippos".

Comment: @DVK: Because you are associating the supply and demand from one thing (available prostitutes) and another thing (humans trafficked) as if there were no other influences. It makes intuitive sense but it is still speculation. For instance, the legalization of prostitution could theoretically reduce the *risk* of trafficking since all trafficked workers can work unhindered because the work is no longer illegal. Or, in other words, you are assuming that the increase in supply is coming from non-trafficked persons in order to suggest there would be no increase in trafficking.

Comment: It could be noted that media coverage of trafficking increased in Sweden after Sweden made prostitution illegal. But as per my answer, there is no statistics about it available as trafficking was not treated separately from other related crimes before 2003. But it seems to have increased. There were several raids on brothels with trafficked girls in the early 2000's, something that was unheard of just years before.

Comment: If you think what @KonradRudolph is pointing out is just a semantics game, you should read Robert Heinlein's novella "Logic of Empire."

Answer (score 8):

Germany changed their laws in 2002, making prostitution equal to any job, so you have to pay taxes and get social security etc. There is no indication this increased the amount of trafficking. But then again prostitution was semi-legal already before 2002.

Ref: http://research.icmpd.org/1465.html

Sweden criminalized prostitution in 1999. One of the stated arguments was lowering trafficking. Unfortunately there was no statistics available before 2003 (see above ref), so we don't know if it has increased or decreased.

So there is no data to say either way.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the failure of Nevada to collect hard data in the past, the State Department commission Dr. Melissa Farley to study prostitution and trafficking in Nevada and compile an empirical report.  The results were far worse than most would have anticipated.

"Prostitution and Trafficking in Nevada" addresses the scope of the sex industry in Nevada, including human rights violations against women in the Nevada legal brothels. The book describes how the multibillion-dollar illegal sex industry in Las Vegas works. Sex trafficking from within and outside of the US, advertising for prostitution, political corruption, pornography, organized crime and the constant demand of men for paid sex - all contribute to prostitution and trafficking in Nevada.

> Legalization of prostitution in Nevada, Germany, Australia and the Netherlands has resulted in an increase in illegal, hidden, and street prostitution. Decriminalization and legalization promote sex trafficking. Germany and the Netherlands are currently reconsidering whether to get rid of legal prostitution because of these social problems.

[Myths & Facts About Nevada Legal Prostitution](http://www.prostitutionresearch.com/faq/000146.html)

Also read the fact sheet here.:

http://www.nevadacoalition.org/factsheets/LegliznFactSheet091707c.pdf

**Edit:**

Maybe you should refrain from making such a judgment until you read the report (which actually turned into a book) that is full of well-documented, scientifically-gathered, verifiable and replicatable data.

You might not be of the opinion it is credible, but John Miller, (Research Professor of International Affairs, George Washington University; Ambassador at Large on Modern Day Slavery 2004-2006; Senior Advisor to the Secretary of State 2002-2006; Director of the Office to Monitor and Combat Trafficking) is an expert at both research and the topic of trafficking, and he called it a must read.

> "Finally, here's a book about sex
>   slavery not just in distant lands but
>   in Nevada, USA. If you've wanted to
>   know what really goes on in the sex
>   industry in Las Vegas and nearby
>   Nevada counties, this is an unpleasant
>   but must read."

[http://www.prostitutionresearch.com/prostitution_research/000168.html](http://www.prostitutionresearch.com/faq/000146.html)

Here's a study published in the Yale Journal of Law and Feminism.

[http://www.prostitutionresearch.com/laws/000151.html](http://www.nevadacoalition.org/factsheets/LegliznFactSheet091707c.pdf)

Check the references - those below are just a snippet.

> Sexual violence and physical assault
>   are the norm for women in all types of
>   prostitution. One Canadian observer
>   noted that ninety-nine percent of
>   women in prostitution were victims of
>   violence, with more frequent injuries
>   “than workers in [those] occupations
>   considered . . . most dangerous, like
>   mining, forestry, and firefighting.”20
>   Prostituted women in Glasgow said that
>   violence from customers was their
>   primary fear.21 Physical abuse was
>   considered part of the job of
>   prostitution, with the payment
>   sometimes determined by each
>   individual blow of a beating or
>   whipping.22
>
> Violence is commonplace in
>   prostitution whether it is legal or
>   illegal.23 Eighty-five percent of
>   prostituted women interviewed in
>   Minneapolis-St. Paul had been raped in
>   prostitution.24 Another study found
>   that eighty percent of women who had
>   been domestically or transnationally
>   trafficked suffered violence-related
>   injuries.25 Of 854 people in
>   prostitution in nine countries,
>   eighty-nine percent wanted to leave
>   prostitution but did not have other
>   options for survival.26 Researchers
>   have found that two factors are
>   consistently associated with greater
>   violence in prostitution: poverty and
>   length of time in prostitution. The
>   more customers serviced, the more
>   women reported severe physical
>   symptoms.27 The longer women remained
>   in prostitution, the higher their
>   rates of sexually transmitted
>   diseases.28 When prostitution is
>   assumed to be a reasonable “job
>   option,” women’s intense longing to
>   escape it is made invisible.29

From policyinnovations.org you can find this:

> "According to a study published in the
>   American Journal of Epidemiology, the
>   average age of death of prostitutes is
>   34. In the United States, the rate at which prostitutes are killed in the
>   workplace is 51 times that of the next
>   most dangerous occupation for women,
>   working in a liquor store. Other
>   studies show that nine out of ten
>   prostitutes urgently want to escape
>   the job. Almost half have attempted
>   suicide at least once."

And much more. There is research available.

Comment: Could you please add a proper reference to Melissa Farley’s study? Furthermore, the distinct claims also need sourcing, e.g. the fact that in Germany, Australia and the Netherlands there was an increase in illegal street prostitution, that this was a result of the decriminalisation and that as a result there are serious considerations to illegalise it. I live in Germany and I’ve never heard of either of these claims. The website you cite contains *one* source which mentions “Germany” in the abstract and this is merely a collection of cherry-picked, spiteful anecdotes without proper analysis.

Comment: Furthermore, this source also fails abysmally to follow an appropriate, objective, impartial academic style, calling its credibility into question. I’m really not sure what to make of such a “study”. Also, assertions such as “the constant demand of men for paid sex” is subjective, idle speculation and doesn’t belong here. (PS: I had almost upvoted this answer before looking at the sources.)

Comment: The "factsheet" which contains very few facts and a lot of clearly biased nonsense claims, is still available. The other links no longer works.

Comment: Melissa Farley was also, specifically, an anti-pornography and anti-prostitution activist. She may have had solid empirical reasons for being so, but, clearly, commissioning her to do this "study" was a political exercise with a 100% certain expected result.